# cvs ci, how to suppress on screen output of "cvs commit: Examining..."

Tags: cvs

In cvs ci of a repository containing thousands of files,  there are lots of on screen output such as "cvs commit: Examining..."

Is there an option to suppress such output for files that are not changed, and show such output only for files that have been changed?

Comment: what language, library are you using? Where is the code? Your question tells us absolutely nothing

Comment: your comment shows you do not know what cvs is, it is an old version control tool (nowadays mostly replaced by git) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System.   It can version control any file (let alone language).  Maybe you are too new to know cvs/svn ?

Comment: chatGPT suggests -q option, but clearly cvs ci does not have such a quiet-mode option via -q,  and  chatGPT quickly accepts its error once I show it the error message using -q.  But chatGPT  does not have an answer to suppress the output.

Comment: You could explicitly commit only the changed files (that you previously identify via other cvs commands).

Comment: if you work with hundreds or thousands of files, then you would appreciate the huge convenience of an option such as -q  (quiet mode)

Comment: Agreed. Been there, done that. But CVS hasn't been updated for 15+ years. I mean 1.12 never made it to official status. So there's no point pining for missing features.